# Two very similar SpringMVC projects. One fails to display model data

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I've made two projects, both are very basic Spring MVC with basic configurations and a single controller. Some of the files in both projects are IDENTICAL like the controller, view and view-resolver definition. This is done for the purpose of finding what is causing the failure: In **projectA** the view fails to display the model data sent by the controller. **projectB** works fine.
(I am using Spring 4.3.9 and Tomcat 8.5.20)

**project A** - Dispatcher servlet defined by extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. `getRootConfigClasses()` returns a config class which links web-config.xml which define the view resolver.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── mywebapp
        │       ├── config
        │       │   ├── MyWebAppInitializer.java
        │       │   └── RootConfig.java
        │       └── web
        │           └── HomeController.java
        ├── resources
        │   └── web-config.xml
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── views
                │   └── home.jsp
                └── web.xml
```

**project B** - Dispatcher defined in web.xml. Servlet-context and root-context linked in web.xml.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── mywebapp
        │       └── web
        │           └── HomeController.java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── app-config.xml
        │   └── web-config.xml
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── views
                │   └── home.jsp
                └── web.xml
```

**project A** returns

```
Hello World!

${message} 
${message}
```

**project B** returns

```
Hello World!

my message in model 
my message in model
```

Since both projects use IDENTICAL:

**a**) JSP view.
**b**) Controller for said view.
**c**) config file defining the view resolver.(web-config.xml)

and the root-context files (app-config.xml and RootConfig.java) serve only as links between servlet-context files and dispatcher definition, the cause of failure must come from java-config of the dispatcher servlet. But I can't find it.

**MyWebAppInitializer.java** from **project A**

```
package mywebapp.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**web.xml** from **project B**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <display-name>Spring MVC XML Configuration Example</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:app-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:web-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**web-config.xml** - shared by BOTH projects

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mywebapp.web" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**HomeController.java** - shared by **BOTH** projects

```
package mywebapp.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "my message in model");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Please help me find the cause for failure to display the model data so I can have a working java-config template.

RootConfig.java from **project A**

```
package mywebapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan (basePackages={"mywebapp"}, excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
@ImportResource("classpath:web-config.xml")
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Comment: Please show your `RootConfig` class.

Comment: @Jason just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1)
In **project A** - delete `web.xml` created by maven archetype.

Step 2) Add the following to `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```